# Laravel deleting a thread of a forum

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I already searched and tried a lot of solutions of similar case but nothing works for my case. I'm still pretty new to Laravel and don't really understand about eloquent. I'm trying to delete thread of a forum, please help.

This is the route for deleting threads:

```
Route::get('/forum/{forum_id}/thread/{thread_id}/delete', [
'uses' => 'ForumsController@deleteThread',
'as' => 'thread.delete']);
```

This is the function (i don't know how to get the thread id):

```
    public function deleteThread($id)
    {
        $forum = Forum::find($id);
        $thread = $forum->threads;

        dd($thread);
        $thread->delete();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

This is the delete button:

```
<a href="{{ route('thread.delete', ['forum_id' => $forum->id, 'thread_id' => $thread->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

This is the Forum model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Forum extends Model
{
    public function threads () {
        return $this->hasMany(Thread::class);
    }
}
```

This is the Thread Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thread extends Model
{
    public function forum () {
        return $this->belongsTo(Forum::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your route looks like this:

```
Route::get('/forum/{forum_id}/thread/{thread_id}/delete', [ ... ])
```

you'll have to use `forum_id` and `thread_id` as parameters of your controller function:

```
public function deleteThread($forum_id, $thread_id)
{
    $forum = Forum::find($forum_id);
    $thread = Thread::find($thread_id);

    $thread->delete();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

You could even let Laravel inject the `Forum` and `Thread` into the controller for you - by type-hinting them on the function:

```
public function deleteThread(Forum $forum, Thread $thread)
{
    $thread->delete();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Of course you'd have to adjust the `forum_id` parameter of the route to `forum` and the `thread_id` to `thread` respectively. This also requires to change the parameters you pass to the URL in other views for example (aka *the delete button*).

**UPDATE**
Just by the way you shouldn't be using a get request for deleting. You should use a `DELETE` HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
public function deleteThread($forum_id,$thread_id)
    {
        Thread::destroy($thread_id);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```